# R: map_dfr + encoding option in read_table()

Tags: r, encoding, whitespace, purrr, csv

I need to use `purrr::map_dfr` function to read a list of files in a folder. They are .txt files with white space delimiter, so I can only use `readr::read_table`. However I need to explicitate the encoding too.

How can I solve the issue? How can I use `map_dfr` function with white space delimited files? Thank you.

Comment: Where does `map_dfr` come from?

Comment: What's the code you've written? I'm not sure how mapping with `read_table`  would differ from using any other function in `map_dfr`

Comment: No, I didn't write no code for this.I did it for tab delimited "|" but now I don't know how to do the same with space delimited.

Comment: Just provide the options you would normally provide to `readr::read_table` as additional named arguments to `purrr::map_dfr`. To specify the encoding, this will likely look something like this: `map_dfr( ...vector of filenames to read..., read_table, locale = ...encoding setting... )`.

Comment: I think the problem is with tidyverse. It seems not support the UTF-16 encoding, at least with white space delimited txt files.